# Extract value by index

Tags: regex

I have this string *82,03,92,23,12,32,43*, and I want to provide a starting and ending position to get a specific value (i.e how would you get 12).

I've tried the following regex:

```
\b(\w+)  this returns 82, it's kind of close of what I'm looking for  
([0-9]*),([0-9]*) this returns 82,03 which is not what I'm looking for
```

I didn't specify any programming languages because I want the regex to be the instruction in a sense, so that the system can compute and return results for any cases of provided. (In a sense we can think of abstractions, so if I use a `slipt` function then I would be like hard coding value for specific case)

Comment: What is your programming language?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that by a regexp alone, as far as I know, in no language, except one would construct an regex on the fly. So in case you would like to access the third value, you would need:

```
/(?:\d+,\d+,)(\d+)/,
```

but there is no way to set a parameter to an regex, at least not in the languages I know…

All you can do is split the string into an array and apply the index there:

```
"32,234,354,223,".split(",")[<idx>]
```

or a while loop + `exec()`:

```
let match = null, finder = /\d+/g, test = '90,32,23', idx = 0;

while ((match = finder.exec(test))!== null) {
  //here your match…
  idx++;
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to use specific code rather a regex to get the value, because this interface that I have extract data from different cases, and the case above is just one of many. so if I use a specific code to extra the data, it makes the system less generic

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string into an array and apply the index on the array. You didnt mentioned your programming language so is an example in C#:

```
string[] index = YourString.Split(',');
```